# Can you help me understand this code .email__input:not(:placeholder-shown).email__input:not(:focus) + .email__label {}?

Tags: html, css

I made an input email box and i have applied a transition on the label. Whenever I was inputting the email it moved upwards. But when I move away it comes back to its place overlapping with the input. So, I searched for a solution and this is a code that I found on the internet.

```
.email__input:not(:placeholder-shown).email__input:not(:focus) + .email__label {}
```

But I don't quite understand how does it work. It will be helpful if you can explain this line to me.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to include more of the code to help troubleshoot the issue with the overlapping elements, but hopefully this helps with your direct question.

`.email__input:not(:placeholder-shown)` - Refers to an element with the class ‘email__input’ that doesn’t have the placeholder text showing.
`.email__input:not(:focus)` - Refers to an element with a class ‘email__input’ that does not have focus.

Given there are no spaces or other combinators between the first two parts, this indicates both must apply.
The ‘+’ combinator signifies the selector following the ‘+’ is a sibling to the selector before it.

Therefore this appears to be specifically targeting the element with the class ‘email__label’ that is an adjacent sibling to an element with a class ‘email__input’ that is both not showing placeholder text AND not given focus.

More information on selectors and combinators can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_combinators.asp